# Which is the better way to return a bunch of struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

There are several ways to return a bunch of struct (A) in C.

The first way is to return a pointer to pointer to struct (A), and make sure the last element of the pointer to pointer is set as `NULL` for telling how many structs (A) are there.

And, the second one is to return a pointer to struct (B, different from above!), and there are two elements in that struct (B) which are n_items and a pointer to array of struct (A).

Which is the better way to return a bunch of struct in C?

Or which is more common, faster and safer than the other one?

Comment: So, basically you are asking whether linked lists or arrays are better data structures?  Well, both have their place but broadly speaking, contiguous arrays are usually faster.

Comment: @5gon12eder Not actually a linked list. It's more similar to [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ23N.gif).

Comment: I see.  Such indirect array (array of pointers to objects) adds an extra layer of indirection, extra overhead and extra complexity.  If you don't need it, you probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more ways to return a bunch of structures:

- Using a pair of output arguments:

  ```
  int get_structs(struct A **outp, size_t *outsize);
  ```

  where the function will allocate an output buffer and return it using the output arguments (similar to the `B` idea, but without needing a separate structure). This is a very common approach.
- Using a linked list:

  ```
  struct node {
     struct A *value;
     struct node *next;
  };
  struct node *get_struct_list();
  ```

  This is handy if the list size needs to be dynamically adjusted.
- Using a preallocated buffer:

  ```
  int get_structs(struct A *outbuf, size_t *bufsize);
  ```

  where the caller provides an allocated buffer and the size of the buffer, and the function fills it up and returns the number of structs actually written. This is useful to avoid allocations in the callee (which can sometimes be very important, e.g. to allow the caller to allocate a single buffer and keep reusing it to avoid expensive allocations).

What you use ultimately depends on your use-case. Without knowing more about your application it's impossible to tell what the best strategy is. All of these techniques can be found used in practice.

---

The two techniques you mentioned are both less common in practice, from my experience. The first one requires that you return a `struct A **`, which has pointers to individually-allocated structures (alternatively, that each structure has some way to indicate that it's the end). The second requires you to define an ephemeral structure used only to return a pair of values, which is more commonly expressed using "output" arguments as above.

Comment: Do you mean `size_t bufsize`?

Comment: Nope. It's an "in/out" parameter - this lets you send in the size of the buffer and, upon return, obtain the size of the modified buffer. The function's return value can be used to signal an error. See, for example, the `recvfrom` function from POSIX for an example of an API like this.